# Problems installing Codename One plugin in NetBeans

Tags: codenameone

I have a ploblem during the installation of Codename One plugin in Netbeans.

After the installation it says to restart the IDE.

After IDE restarts it's like if I've never installed the plugin: it asks me to install from the beginning.

NetBeans 12 on Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans 12 changed a lot about the way plugins should be built and our plugin is a bit out of date by now.

However, we won't be updating it since it's no longer necessary as we migrated to maven. You can learn about that here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/moving-to-maven.html

Comment: Current projects still based on Ant, in theory, should be able to work without the plugin, or am I wrong? If so, perhaps it would make sense to remove the plugin so as to avoid confusing new users?

Comment: For Ant it would be more convenient to use the plugin.

Comment: in netbeans 8.2 the plugin have many times without receive updates Why? I install the netbeans 12 and I prefer the 8.2 because the simulator run very fast in the 8.2 insted 12. Any idea why this behaivor?

Comment: NetBeans changed a few behaviors in newer versions and moved to a different parsing architecture. This would require a major refactoring of the plugin. Eclipse is even worse as we literally can no longer compile the plugin due to IDE changes. The move to maven essentially renders all of these problems null and void. So we decided to pull the plug on those and leave them only for legacy support.